# Images not uploading to server path PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I have the directory photo_gallery (with 777 permissions) created in the same level as the Noticias.php file

It gives me no error, but the file is not showing in the photo_gallery folder.

This is my PHP code:

```
$error=array();
$extension=array("jpeg","jpg","png","gif");
foreach($_FILES["imagenes"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name)
        {

            $file_name=$_FILES["imagenes"]["name"][$key];
            $file_tmp=$_FILES["imagenes"]["tmp_name"][$key];
            $ext=pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if(in_array($ext,$extension))
            {

                if(!file_exists("photo_gallery/".$file_name))
                {
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp=$_FILES["imagenes"]["tmp_name"][$key],"photo_gallery/".$file_name);
                }
                else
                {
                    $filename=basename($file_name,$ext);
                    $newFileName=$filename.time().".".$ext;
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp=$_FILES["imagenes"]["tmp_name"][$key],"photo_gallery/".$newFileName);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                array_push($error,"$file_name, ");

            }
        }
```

And HTML:

```
<form  action="Noticias.php" method="post" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    div class="form-group">
    <p>Imágenes</p>
    <input type="file" name="imagenes[]" class="form-control" id="imagenes"  placeholder="Imágenes" multiple="multiple"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: *"It gives me no error"* - Are you checking for them, that's the question. and where's the html for this?

Comment: As a further improvement, also have a variable which increments on successful upload.  This way you know which ones failed

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($file_tmp=$_FILES` that alone should be throwing you an error.

Comment: Also your foreach loop doesn't do anything. You never use the `$tmp_name` variable

Comment: I corrected the loop. I edited the code above. Still does not uploads the image, I will add teh HTML too @Akintunde

Comment: @Akitunde could you see my edit?

Answer (score 0):

move_uploaded_file() needs as second parameter the folder and the filename of the new location.

You should to do something like this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagenes"]["tmp_name"][$key], "photo_gallery/your_filename.png");
```

I hope that help you.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you, I added that to the code but still. I edited above

Answer (score -2):

give the file path as

```
./photo_gallery/
```

try liker this. This may help you.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that this will solve the question. Both `photo_gallery/` and `./photo_gallery/` do the same thing.

Comment: There are lots of issues besides the path. Go through the code again please